# Extract rows based on values from text file using Python

Tags: python, extract

I have a list of information in file A that I want to extract according to the numbering in file B. If given the value 4 and 5, all the 4th column in file A with the value 4 and 5 will be extracted. May I know how can I do this using python? can anyone help me? The code below only extract based on index that have value 4.

```
with open("B.txt", "rt") as f:
    classes = [int(line) for line in f.readlines()]
    with open("A.txt", "rt") as f:
        lines = [line for index, line in enumerate(f.readlines()) if classes[index]== 4]
        lines_all= "".join(lines)

with open("C.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(lines_all)
```

**A.txt**

```
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  36  42  1
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  109 129 2
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  110 130 2
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  129 149 2
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  130 150 2
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  157 163 3
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  157 165 3
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  179 185 4
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  197 217 5
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  220 226 6
```

**B.txt**

```
4
5
```

**Desired output**

```
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  179 185 4
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  197 217 5
```

Comment: A good start would be to go to the documentation for CSV and pandas. Both are Python modules for you to look at which would help you.

Comment: Okay. With the edit you have posted a complete question. My vote for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open("B.txt", "r") as target_file:
    target = [i.strip() for i in target_file]

with open("A.txt", "r") as data_file:
    r = filter(lambda x: x.strip().rsplit(None, 1)[1] in target, data_file)

print "".join(r)
```

the output:

```
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  179 185 4
hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003  197 217 5
```

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794668/extract-rows-based-on-values-from-text-file-using-python/30794778#comment49639032_30794764) by @Padraic, I change the `split()[-1]` to `rsplit(None, 1)[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

create a set of the lines/numbers from the b file the compare the last element from each row in f1 to the elements in the set:

```
import  csv    
with open("a.txt") as f, open("b.txt") as f2:
    st = set(line.rstrip() for line in f2)
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter=" ")
    data = [row for row in r if row[-1] in st]
    print(data)

[['hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003', '179', '185', '4'], ['hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003', '197', '217', '5']]
```

set `delimiter=` to whatever it is or don't set it at all if your file is comma separated.

Or:

```
with open("a.txt") as f, open("b.txt") as f2:
    st = set(line.rstrip() for line in f2)
    data = [line.rstrip() for line in f if line.rsplit(None, 1)[1] in st ]
    print(data)
['hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003 179 185 4', 'hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003 197 217 5']
```

Comment: The output is not he wanted. See my answer.

Comment: @liushuaikobe, what are you talking about exactly? Your code is just a less efficient version of what I provided

Comment: There's no need to `import csv` and, the output of your first approach is a list nested list, which isn't the desired output.

Comment: @liushuaikobe, depending on what the OP actually wants to do with the data which neither you nor I know because we are not the OP will decide what format is best, what you do in your code is actually exactly what the csv module does, you split every single line completely in your filter then rejoin, you just do it with a lot more overhead, that and your solution is quadratic.

Comment: I like the use of `set`, I keep forgetting about it but of course important if B.txt is quite large...  Is there a reason to prefer `rsplit(None, 1)[1]` over `split()[3]`?

Comment: @zehnpaard, we only split once from the right as opposed to splitting on every whitespace i.e `'hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003 197 217 5' -> ['hg17_ct_ER_ER_1003 197 217 ,'5']`

Comment: Right, again more efficient given we're looking at the last column, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @zehnpaard, no worries.